# How to prevent swapping on Mac OS X?

Tags: osx, swap

I am inclined to run Tails through a virtual machine so that I could chain two VPNs. One running through the host Mac osx and one more running from inside the virtual machine that's running Tails.

However on Tails website, it says that host operating systems likely uses swapping which copies part of the RAM to the hard drive. Is there a command or program that prevents swapping on Mac osx?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](http://wiki.summercode.com/how_to_disable_or_enable_swapping_in_mac_os_x), you can use:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.dynamic_pager.plist
```

Comment: So I can put that in command in the terminal and it should help prevent swapping?

Comment: It will turn swapping off, not just help. In your case where you don't want anything saved to disk it should work, but I'm far from an expert on osx. If the only place it might save to disk is the swap and this is the only command needed to turn off swap then it will work.